# Show data in a listview from remote server

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

This is something I've been trying for quite a while and this is the closest I have come. Hopefully someone can help me take this the extra step to actually fill up a ListView. At the moment the data is retrieved as it shows up in my logcat. I need it to appear in the actual application now in the form of a ListView since there are two columns.

My code is quite long so here is a link to it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/XzTtTJ3j

The current code has no errors, it doesn't throw any of the exceptions but of course at the same time it does nothing. Just shows my data in the logcat as a string, the page in the application is blank. I've looked at tutorials and when I've tried to implement them I get errors. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact I'm using AsyncTask..? My layout file consists of two textviews and a listview in a relativelayout.

Any ideas? Would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to show your onPostExecute()?  doInBackground()'s return value should be processed in onPostExecute() and do necessary UI updates there.

Comment: You see that's something I've had trouble with. More so because I have been busying getting this far with my code.

So in theory if I put "return output;" into the OnPostExecute it should work?

Comment: Well, doInBackground() doesn't natively communicate with the UI thread, so that's where onPostExecute() comes in.  You will, of course, still need to do some work to update your ListView with the results.    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)

Comment: Yeah fair enough, I know the code at the moment has no mention of a ListView but if onPostExecute is needed then that could be why I was getting errors from a few tutorials. I guess I should learn how to use that first then put the ListView code within that.

Comment: If you post the information as an answer I can accept it as the answer mate. It's what I'm going to try, seems to be the right thing to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to show your onPostExecute()? doInBackground()'s return value should be processed in onPostExecute() and do necessary UI updates there.

doInBackground() doesn't natively communicate with the UI thread, so that's where onPostExecute() comes in. You will, of course, still need to do some work to update your ListView with the results.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)

Comment: It worked! Something I should have looked into before if I'm honest but there you go. I just tested it with a TextView rather than a ListView so everything is all over the place but obviously putting that into a ListView should be fine. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad it was a simple fix.